# Importing RepositoryMining from pydriller doesn't work

Tags: python, pip, configure

I have the following line of code `from pydriller import RepositoryMining`, and I get the following error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'RepositoryMining' from 'pydriller'`. I've installed pydriller in Pycharm from Settings->Project:projectName -> Python Interpreter and I added it there. I've also tried to uninstall it and install it again with pip from cmd, and run the main.py from cmd, but I get the same error. I have python 3.9.13 and pydriller 2.5.1. Do you have any sugestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. However, it was gone when I used `from pydriller import Repository` instead of `from pydriller import RepositoryMining`

I am not sure, how it is solved. However, I have a guess that I did not created a virtual environment. Maybe it is because of that.

Thanks.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35590659)